# Mystery shapes - making shapes from vague descriptions

Tags: calculus

I am suppose to mentally create something that has base $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ and the cross sections perpendicular to the x axis are triangles whose height and base are equal.

What is going on? I tried to graph it but it was too hard, is this like a turtle? Sphere on back, pointy spikes on the bottom? What does "triangles" mean? How many? 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: you have a "cone" in 3D: and I'm assuming you can take the x-y plane as where the cone sits: its base is a circle of radius $1$. Think of an upside-down ice-cream cone with no ice-cream, whose height is equal to the diameter of the circle. Can you fill in more of the details? Try to envision how "steep" the cone must be from the circumference of the base of the cone, to its tip.

---

Added: The cross section will be an equilateral triangle: If we call of the base "2y", then 1/2 base will be y, but since we have that height will equal base, (given), we must have $2y$. *cross sectional Area* (area of triangle) will then be $$A = \frac 12\;\text{base}\, \times\, \text{height} = (y)(2y) = 2y^2.\tag{Area}$$ Now, we know that $x^2 + y^2 = 1$, so $y^2 = 1 - x^2 \implies 2y^2 = 2(1 - x^2)$. Substituting this into our equation for area, to get an equation $A(x)$ in terms of $x$ gives us $$A(x) = 2y^2 = 2(1-x^2) = 2 - 2x^2\tag{A(x)}$$ Now, we want to sum  the area of all cross sections (triangles) between $x = -1\;\text{and}\; x = 1$, to determine the volume $V$ of the cone:

$$V = \int_{-1}^1 A(x)\, dx = \int_{-1}^1 (2-2x^2)\, dx$$

Comment: A cone has a circle for its base not a sphere.

Comment: I said an ice-cream cone with **no** ice-cream (hollow): $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ is the equation of a circle here.

Comment: I am saying that the base of a circle in 3d is a sphere isn't it?

Comment: A sphere in 3d has the equation, e.g., $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$. By itself, $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ describes an infinite cylinder, in your case, we need for perpendicular cross sections to be triangules, hence, we have a cone. In order for height and base to be measurable, we would need to have "cut-offs": a situated base, and a definitive height.

Comment: I don't understand what is going on here. Is there an implied 3d property to this circle? How is this a shape at all?

Comment: How do I find the volume?

Comment: All my questions are getitng down voted and no one will help me. How do I determine what the slice is?

Comment: Young Miss Marple, solve the Mystery well +1:-)

Comment: You aren't making sense.

Comment: All of that, I don't understand this problem at all. How can I know the height? I still have variable hieght and y./

Comment: I dont get it how do i know what y is i habe that the base is the circle but how do i know height

Comment: I think you made a mistake, this is a cone the cross sections should be circles.

Comment: Please delete the excess, repeated comments! In your post, you state that it is given that the height of the triangle is equal to its base. Since we are taking base to be 2y, that means height will be 2y. To calculate the area of a cross-sectional triangle, we take $1/2$ base x height = $\frac 12(2y)(2y) = 2y^2$

Comment: Quoting your post: "and the cross sections **perpendicular** to the x axis are **triangles** whose **height and base are equal**." We are slicing the cone from top-bottom (perpendicular to the xy plane, indeed, slices which are perpendicular to the x axis) between $x = -1, x = 1$, we are not slicing by taking cross sections that are parallel to the x-y plane (which would be circles.)

Comment: I don't understand this. How am I suppose to learn about all this stuff? i can't get it I don't have time to get this si there some simpe trick to memorize? ijust need some formula to memorize I can't do this I can't learn how to think in 3d shapes in an x y z plane described by 2d linear graph points/.

Answer (score 3):

This screenshot from Calculus Early Transcendentals (6th Ed.) by Stewart might help:

[image]

Note that the example is slightly different; each cross section has a base of $2y$ and a height of $\sqrt{3}y$, whereas in your example you want a base of $2y$ and a height of $2y$. So your $3$D diagram should be similar, except more vertically stretched.

Comment: How do I find the volume?

Comment: @justanguy If $A(x)$ represents the cross sectional area, than we have:
$$
A(x)=\dfrac{1}{2}(2y)(2y)=2y^2=2(1-x^2)=2-2x^2
$$
Hence, the volume is given by:
$$
V = \int_{-1}^1 A(x) dx = \int_{-1}^1 (2-2x^2) dx
$$

Comment: I don't follow where you got 1/2 2y or any of that at all really.

Comment: @justanguy The area of a triangle is half the product of its base and height. I substituted the base of $2y$ and the height of $2y$. I then used the fact that the equation of the circle is $x^2+y^2=1$ to replace $y^2$ with $1-x^2$.

Comment: How did you get the base and height?

Comment: @justanguy The base in your example is the same as the base in the example from my screenshot. Do you understand how they got their base? Once we know the base, we automatically get the height as well, since we are given that they are equal.

Comment: How do we know they are equal? I dont understand what a cross section is/

Comment: I really need help I can't do any of these, I injured my hand and can't type well and I have 8 hours of homewokr still.

Comment: @justanguy I knew that the height equalled the base because (quoted directly from your question): "the cross sections perpendicular to the $x$ axis are triangles whose height and base are equal". Note that the pink triangle in Figure $13(c)$ is a cross-section. The line segment $AB$ is the base of the triangle and has a length of $y+y=2y$, so the height is also $2y$.

Comment: I don't know what that means for there to be invisible triangles in this problem, I can't conceptualize that into a formula/.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9394/discussion-between-adriano-and-justanguy)